# member access in c++ address misaligned

Tags: c++, list, merge, linked-list, runtime

I want to merge two sorted list but it shows some runtime error member access within misaligned address.. I want to make new list from those two linked list in sorted way. 
Here I am maintaining current pointer for each list i.e. l1,l2,l3. If current pointer values are equal then increment pointer for both list and add those values in l3 list.

```
class Solution {
public:
    ListNode* mergeTwoLists(ListNode* l1, ListNode* l2) {
        ListNode* l3;
        ListNode* current1=l1;
        ListNode* current2=l2;
        ListNode* current3;

        while(current1&&current2)
        {
            if(current1->val==current2->val)
            {
                ListNode* temp1=(ListNode*)malloc(sizeof(struct ListNode));
                ListNode* temp2=(ListNode*)malloc(sizeof(struct ListNode));
                temp1->val=current1->val;
                temp1->next=NULL;
                temp2->val=current2->val;
                temp2->next=NULL;
                current1=current1->next;
                current2=current2->next;
                if(!l3)
                {
                    l3=temp1;
                    current3=l3;

                }
                else
                {
                    current3->next=temp1;
                    current3=current3->next;                               
                }
                   current3->next=temp2;
                    current3=current3->next;
                    current3->next=NULL;
            }
            else if(current1->val>current2->val)
            {
                ListNode* temp1=(ListNode*)malloc(sizeof(struct ListNode));
                temp1->val=current2->val;
                current2=current2->next;
                if(!l3)
                {
                    l3=temp1;
                    current3=l3;
                }
                else
                {
                    current3->next=temp1;
                    current3=current3->next;
                    current3->next=NULL;
                }


            }
            else
            {
                ListNode* temp1=(ListNode*)malloc(sizeof(struct ListNode));
                temp1->val=current1->val;
                temp1->next=NULL;
                current1=current1->next;
                if(!l3)
                {
                    l3=temp1;
                    current3=l3;
                }
                else
                {
                    current3->next=temp1;
                    current3=current3->next;
                    current3->next=NULL;
                }

            }
        }
        if(current1||current2)
        {
            while(current1)
            {
                ListNode* temp1=(ListNode*)malloc(sizeof(struct ListNode));
                temp1->val=current1->val;
                current1=current1->next;
                if(!l3)
                {
                    l3=temp1;
                    current3=l3;
                }
                else
                {
                    current3->next=temp1;
                    current3=current3->next;
                    current3->next=NULL;
                }
            }

            while(current2)
            {
                ListNode* temp1=(ListNode*)malloc(sizeof(struct ListNode));
                temp1->val=current2->val;
                current2=current2->next;
                if(!l3)
                {
                    l3=temp1;
                    current3=l3;
                }
                else
                {
                    current3->next=temp1;
                    current3=current3->next;
                    current3->next=NULL;
                }
            }
        }
        return l3;
       }
};
```

Comment: Your program exhibits undefined behavior, by way of accessing an uninitialized variable `l3`

Comment: `if(!l3)` What does this statement supposed to do here?